# Forcing NetBeans 7.3 to recompile project on test run?

Tags: testing, netbeans, netbeans-7, recompile

When I click "Debug test file" in NetBeans on certain class, it is run against the binaries compiled from the last build.

I'd like NetBeans to recompile, but I can't find how to achieve that.

Also, it seems that sometimes the recompile happens - i.e. Maven is invoked. Must mostly I get runs with obsolete binaries.

How can I force NetBeans to recompile before running a (single) test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling Compile on Save feature in project properties should do. Then Maven build is executed all the time. Please note that in upcoming 7.4, Maven builds are always executed but with Compile on Save turned on, the phase execution is skipped.